# VB.NET Skip characters

Tags: vb.net, character

I'm using a wildcard on a string. and then i put the result on another string.

```
dim Wild1 as string = "ab Ab AB ?? ?? ??"
dim Wild2 as string = "ba Ba BA ?? ?? ??"

dim result1 as string = searcher(wild1)
dim result2 as string = searcher(wild2)
```

now, the problem here is that i want to replace the whatever 3 last digits that were found on `result1` to whatever 3 last digits that were found in `result 2`

so i want my program to count the length. or skip the first digits

Comment: Can you post final result, too here in your question?

Comment: the last 3 digits in the result are random. it could be any letters. thats why i use wildcard

Answer (score 0):

To get the last three characters, you can use a substring:

```
Dim text As String = "ABC DEF GHI"
Dim last3 As String = text.Substring(text.Length - 3, 3)
```

`last3`, in this example, equals `GHI`.

Then, if you need to replace part of another string with `last3`:

```
Dim text2 As String = "JKL MNO PQR"
text2 = text2.Remove(text2.Length - 3, 3) & last3
```

This then gives you, for `text2`, `JKL MNO GHI`.

(I am not sure if this is what you needed because your question is a bit unclear.)